# Как отключить оптимизацию copy elision?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Ситуация заключается в том, что не могу отключить copy elision. В проекте присутствуют конструкторы с глобальными побочными эффектами. В результате "пропуска копии", при передаче в конструктор копирования объекта из функции - возникает поведение, которое недопустимо в имеющейся ситуации.

Необходимо производить некоторые действия во время вызова конструктора копирования. И вызов конструктора копирования должен происходить при копировании локального объекта перед выходом из функции, а затем - при копировании результата функции в другой объект.

Возможно ли отключить эту оптимизацию? Например, следующий пример (упрощенный) должен вызывать конструктор копии дважды:

```
T func(size_t Value)
{
T t { Value };
// ...
return t;// Первый вызов конструктора копии.
}
// ...
T t_var = func(x);// Второй вызов конструктора копии
```

Comment: компилятор всё правильно сделал. У конструктора копирования не должно быть side-effects

Comment: А нельзя ли эту самую семантику побочного эффекта сделать явной? И явно вызывать. Расскажите о том, какой смысл вашей задачи.

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/post/252885/

Comment: Понял, спасибо. Описать задачу, к сожалению, не могу. Значит конструкторы никогда не должны вызывать побочных эффектов (изменение глобальных счетчиков и пр)?

Comment: на то он и конструктор копирования, что он должен копировать. а не модифицировать.

Comment: По возможности, не должны. Это одно из немногих мест, где язык требует от вас строгую семантику.

Comment: можно сменить компилятор, тогда можно copy elision отключить вообще. Но это неправильно, всё равно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Copy elision (aka RVO) для `return` работает только если выражение в `return` - это имя локальной не-volatile переменной (см. [`[class.copy] p31`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy#31)).

Используйте identity-функцию, тогда копирование при возврате значения не будет убираться.

```
template<typename T> const T& no_copy_elision(const T& t) { return t; }

T func() {
  T t;
  return no_copy_elision(t);
}
```

Либо можно попробовать использовать обычный `static_cast<T>(t)`, или например в комбинации с `volatile`:

```
return static_cast<volatile T&>(t);
```

Однако VC++ может проигнорировать стандарт и всеравно сделать NRVO. Или применить какую-нибудь другую оптимизацию.
В любом случае, не следует использовать побочные эффекты при копировании, оно для этого не предназначено.

Comment: +1, но почему бы компилятору не заинлайнить функции `no_copy_elision` и `func` (as-if rule)? RVO не будет, будет просто элиминация конструктора копирования (которая по идее разрешена всегда).

Comment: @Abyx Окей, я просто не хотел, чтобы у вашего поста была пометка правки другого человека (ну, не приятно же), в планах было сообщить и удалить комментарий :)
А вот еще заодно тогда спрошу, я раньше думал, что _RVO (NRVO)_ и _copy ellision_ - это несколько разные вещи, например, `TestClass obj = TestClass();` - это же не _RVO_, или я где-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: @Abyx Да, но на wiki посты, фактически, анонимные (ну, на самом деле в истории страницы можно посмотреть, но там за посты никто плюсы/минусы не ставит), а здесь ответ определенного человека, и лично мне кажется странным лезть и подправлять чужой ответ (ну, вдруг человек обидится за такое).
И спасибо за разъяснение по видам _copy elision_ :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive: Если редактирование не разрушительное, а доброжелательное, в помощь тексту, это в порядке. Вот если кто-то меняет авторский стиль, или хуже того меняет смысл сообщения, это уже хуже.

Comment: Если быть полностью точным, то в обоих примерах всё равно RVO один раз отработает, для той части, где локальная переменная, которая возвращается, копируется в другое место, которое и будет возвращено. В студии нельзя отключить эту оптимизацию, зато в gcc&clang можно(`-fno-elide-constructors`).